# Module not found in npm own package with React

Tags: reactjs, npm

I want to create my own npm package and inside of this package I want to set only UI components builded for React. I have created a simple button component and I am using styled-components as a styles. When I want to use my package inside another React app I am getting this error:

> ./node_modules/coding-roots/index.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'atoms/Button' in '/Users/<my_name>/Desktop/learning/react/todo/node_modules/coding-roots'

Button.js

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const PrimaryButton = ({ children }) => {
  return <Button>{children}</Button>;
};

const Button = styled.button`
  padding: 0.3rem 0.7rem;
  border: 2px solid var(--primary-color);
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: var(--white-color);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  &:hover {
    background-color: var(--white-color);
    color: var(--primary-color);
  }
`;

export default PrimaryButton;
```

Main index.js for my package:

```
const PrimaryButton = require("atoms/Button");

module.exports = {
  PrimaryButton,
};
```

And this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "coding-roots",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/coding-tree/coding-roots.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/coding-tree/coding-roots/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/coding-tree/coding-roots#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
    "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^6.1.17",
    "@storybook/addon-console": "^1.2.3",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^6.1.17",
    "@storybook/addon-storysource": "^6.1.17",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.1.5",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "storybook": "^6.1.17",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.13",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.1.17",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.1.17",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.1.17",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.1.17",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: How does your import look like? How did you install it (or at least tried to installed it) in your main project?

Comment: Use "./atoms/Button" as you are referring to the same directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same directory should be referred as

```
import PrimaryButton from './atoms/Button';
```

instead of

```
const PrimaryButton = require("atoms/Button");
```

Comment: Updated as above. Please note i have used es6 syntax and it works for me. Storybook rendered without any error in browser.

Comment: Yeah storybook is rendered but I want to use this Button and package in real app now, storybook is working properly from start

Comment: Did you rebuild the project and package after the change ? Please share how did you package the app

Comment: Should I use rollup.js for this? I didn't build this package, simply component and import in index.js

Comment: I didn't know that npm requires commonjs for builded packages, you can edit your answer and I will accept because you pointed me for an answer and if you know more how to do this please describe :) Thanks